# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have a page with the following code on it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    /// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js" />

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
    {
        ToggleTimeDiv();
    }
</script>
```

When the page loads I get the following error:

- Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition.  What is causing this error?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Is your `<script>` block ahead of your ScriptManager?

Answer (score 7):

You should place your script code at the end
of your page, after all your content but just before the  end tag.
between end form tag  and end body tag
 Here’s the code you
need, in its rightful place:

```
   <html>

  ...
   </head>
   <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     ...
    </form>


    enter code here
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  /// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js" />

  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

  function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
  {
      ToggleTimeDiv();
  }
  </script>




   </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you have

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

at the top of your page.. I had same problem.. added this and it works...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET routing, use this line in your global.asax

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd");
    }
```

Comment: This partially worked for me, as without this i was even not getting my css at login page. When i added this, css start showing up, but still getting 
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
and
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined