# Sys.WebForms is undefined in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am doing some partial updates in my Web-Application, but I get the error that "`Sys.WebForms` is undefined in Chrome (latest version)". I have searched a lot on net but couldn't get any valid help.

Please help me out. As I am new at `ASP.Net` and `AJAX`.

The piece of code is as follow:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
```

Comment: are you using IE11? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164753/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanager-is-undefined-error-in-ie11-working-fine-in-ie10

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1932077/1746118

Comment: @nullpointer Well, I am emulating for iPad in Chrome. Basically, I use all browsers. But the priority is Chrome.

Comment: What's your .net framework version? Can you paste the user agent string of that browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The root problem is that the iPad full-screen app gives a user-agent
>   header that ASP.Net does not recognize, so it believes that the
>   browser does not support ajax.  This results in the ScriptManager not
>   including “MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js” and all sort of other things
>   related to ajax panels not loading.

You might need to add below hack to your base page to fix the issue:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request.UserAgent != null && Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
   {
       this.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
   }
}
```

More info here: https://joshmouch.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/sys-webforms-is-undefined-on-ipad/